# Root page in Universal links

Tags: ios, ios-universal-links

How do you set up my apple-app-site-association file to open my app on my homepages root page without using the * wildcard (which, according to apple, is used `'to specify your entire website'`).

```
{
    "appID": "9JA89QQLNQ.com.apple.wwdc",
    "paths": ["/some/sub/page/*", "*"]
}
```

As far as I understand, this would be redundant and hereby I would specify my entire website to be opened in the app, which is something I do not want.

So maybe I need to do something like this:

```
{
    "appID": "9JA89QQLNQ.com.apple.wwdc",
    "paths": ["/some/sub/page/*", "/"]
}
```

Or negate the subpages?

```
{ 
    "appID": "9JA89QQLNQ.com.apple.wwdc", 
    "paths": ["/some/sub/page/*", "*", "NOT */"] 
}
```

Would be great if I could get some thoughts on this!
I've done some research on this, but cannot seem to figure this out.

Additional question: What do I do if I have a questionmark in one of the links I want to use (because that can be used as a wildcard as well)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The path for the root page is `/` — your second example is correct.

A question mark in q URL indicates the beginning of the [query component](http://uri.thephpleague.com/4.0/components/overview/) of the URL — you can't filter Universal Link paths based on this component.